# How can I get the Jbutton wait until the music ends?

Tags: java, swing, audio, jbutton, wait

```
        Playjb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
             try {
                 InputStream in;
                 Path = rs.getString("Path");
                 in = new FileInputStream(new File(Path));
                 AudioStream audios=new AudioStream(in);
                 AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
                 System.out.println("play");  

                 //here I want to add somthing that sets the OKjb 
                 //(another JButton) inactive until the audio is finished.//

             }catch(exception e){

             }
```

Comment: Put it into a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), enable the button in the `done()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Would you please write it down?

Comment: @user3026191 Please considering accepting the answer if it helped you or ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setEnabled() method of JButton and pass it the value false to disable it. When music ends, call it again and pass it the value true to enable it again.

The music should play in the background so use a SwingWorker as suggested. In the doInBackground() disable the button and enable it in done()

Always remember not to put code that will take a long time to execute in the callback methods of the listener. These mehods are just relays to let you know that an event has occured. Any long running task must be offloaded to the background.

Comment: Sure. I can do that but have you figured out how to do that, yet ?

Comment: Not yet!I would be gratefull if you can do that!

Comment: Sure, as soon as I am done with my university work. A couple of hours =]